# How to get domain from email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I get the domain from an email-adress in ruby?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Given the invariant that your input string is a valid email address, you could just write:

```
>> "hey@mycorp.com".split("@").last
=> "mycorp.com"
```

Comment: If your email is invalid (e.g. missing @) then you will get the first part `'wrong'.split('@').last => 'wrong'`, whereas you probably would like to get `nil` or `''`

Comment: @NickRoz, updated my answer to make its premise clearer.

Answer (score 51):

If you prefer using a library dedicated to understanding these things:

```
→ irb -rmail
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Mail::Address.new('feep+wibble@example.com').domain
 => "example.com"
```

Comment: It looks like this library hasn't been updated in 5 years, and (for me at least) doesn't work with ruby2.

Comment: @AndyHayden [Mail](https://rubygems.org/gems/mail) is maintained and it works with Ruby 2.0 and 2.1.  Rails depend on this gem so it must work with recent Rubies.  Most likely one of your gems introduce some version constraints which prohibits you from using the freshest Mail version.

Comment: a dedicated function is more likely to support any weird edge cases

Comment: If you do a benchmark/ips [this version is 32.26x slower](https://gist.github.com/benoittgt/79ef8152e2e78fb09b99)