# How can I extract the domain from an email without using Regex, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Given an email address in the form, `'foo@bar.com'` or `'rhubarb.foo@bar.com'`, how can one extract only the domain `bar` (not `bar.com`), **without** resorting to regex or a specialist library?

This post: '[How to get domain from email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699754/how-to-get-domain-from-email)' *almost* answers my question, but I am unsure how to split domain `'bar.com'`, or whether another approach might exist.

Comment: Why are you opposed to using a regex?

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly; I was opposed to a regex as I didn't want to overlap the question I linked to in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [String#split](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split).

`'foo@bar.com'.split('@')[1].split('.')[0] # => bar`

... or if you need to support subdomains:

`'foo@qux.bar.com'.
  split('@')[1].
  reverse.
  split('.').
  drop(1).
  map(&:reverse).
  reverse.
  join('.') # => qux.bar`

Comment: Fails on addresses with subdomains: `foo@x.bar.com`

Comment: @Mark, I've given some other examples where this fails.

Answer (score 1):

## Partition an Email Address Using Fixed-String Methods

There are a number of string-based approaches, but one of the easiest (at least in my opinion) is to use [String#rpartition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-rpartition) to grab what you need after the terminal `@` symbol in the address. For example, given an address stored in an *email* variable:

```
# Get domain-parts.
email.rpartition('@').last

# Get domain parts without the TLD.
email.rpartition('@').last.rpartition('.').first
```

This is simple, reliable, and (most importantly) relatively easy to read.

### The Rightmost-Partition Method in Action

To see [String#rpartition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-rpartition) in action, and to see how flexible it is even with subdomains or atypical local-parts, consider the results of the following:

```
emails = %w[
  foo@bar.com
  rhubarb.foo@bar.com
  foo@bar.baz.com
  foo+extension.address@subdomain.example.com
]

emails.map { |email| email.rpartition(?@).last.rpartition(?.).first }
#=> ["bar", "bar", "bar.baz", "subdomain.example"]
```

### Use Partitioning for Destructured Assignments

One benefit of using [String#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-partition) or [String#rpartition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-rpartition) over [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-split) is that the two methods provide a natural fit for destructuring assignments. For example:

```
email = "foo+extension.address@subdomain.example.com"

local_part, _, domain_part = email.rpartition ?@
#=> ["foo+extension.address", "@", "subdomain.example.com"]

hostname, _, top_level_domain = domain_part.rpartition ?.
#=> ["subdomain.example", ".", "com"]
```

Because destructuring gives you access to each part in a separate variable, this approach could be useful in creating a variety of alternative representations for your email addresses, such as a hash of domains and the local-parts within each domain. As a trivial example, consider:

```
address_list = Hash.new { |k,v| k[v] = [] }

emails = %w[foo@example.com bar@example.com baz@other.example.com]

emails.each do |email|
  local_part, _, domain_part = email.rpartition ?@
  address_list[domain_part] << local_part
end

address_list
#=> {"example.com"=>["foo", "bar"], "other.example.com"=>["baz"]}
```

Obviously, you could make the structure as simple or as complex as you want. However, complicated structures like `{"com"=>{"example"=>["foo"], "other.example"=>["bar"]}}` are unwieldy, and there's probably an X/Y problem with a simpler solution available. Nevertheless, it's useful to know you can do these sorts of things with de- and restructuring.

Comment: Just curious, why would you use `?@` instead of `"@"` ?. I usually only use this syntax for golfing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the split function:

```
mystring = "bar.com"
mystring.split('.') --> ["bar", "com"]
```

This even works if the string has subdomains:

```
mystring = "night.bar.com"
mystring.split('.') --> ["night", "bar", "com"]
```

edit: Oops, two minutes too late :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are four valid email email addresses:

```
valid_email_addresses = ["a@b.com", "a@b.c.com", "\"a.@.b\"@c.com", "a@b"]
```

See the Wiki for ["Email address"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples).

We can extract the desired strings with the following method.

```
def domain_preface(str)
  # something here like: return nil unless email_address_valid?(str)
  s = str[str.rindex('@')+1..-1]
  i = s.rindex('.')
  return "" unless i
  s[0..s.rindex('.')-1]
end

valid_email_addresses.each { |s| puts "%s: |%s|" % [s, domain_preface(s)] }
a@b.com: |b|
a@b.c.com: |b.c|
"a.@.b"@c.com: |c|
a@b: ||
```